# Run Java program by giving it input using file redirection

Tags: java, command-line

I'm trying to run a Java program using file redirection. I'm testing it with this simple program:

```
package netbeans.sanbdox;

public class Sanbdox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to the command line and run

```
$ java -jar dist/compiled_project.jar < q1.txt
$
```

There's no output, even though `q1.txt` is not an empty file. What should I do to make the file redirection work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Redirecting in that form just replaces `stdin` with a file stream coming from that file. Your code does not use `stdin` for anything, therefore you won't have any output, since you aren't passing any command line arguments to the program.

To see what you're expecting, you'd have to use a `Scanner`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}

scanner.close(); // Not required for stdin but good practice
```

If what you really wanted was to have each token from the file supplied as a command line argument, you could do something like this in your shell:

```
$ java -jar dist/compiled_project.jar $(cat q1.txt)
```

That would output the contents of `q1.txt` as part of the shell command. Odds are it won't work the way you want due to newline characters or other concerns.

Comment: Make sure not to close Scanner if you use the code example above. Else ... closing Scanner will also close System.in and then you will have no more keyboard input to your program!

Answer (score 4):

The input is captured by the `System.in` and not as data passed through the main(String[] args) method when the program starts.

To read that data from the input, read it from `System.in` as an `InputStream` or wrap it in a `Reader`:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

... s.readLine()
```

And make sure to not close the System.in or the Reader, or else you will close keyboard input to your program too!