# How can I execute jar file in UNIX-like using this command line: java -jar mysolution.jar < inputfile.txt

Tags: java, unix, command-line

I tried to use the below command line to execute jar file, but whatever follow the "<" had been omit. I have tried to find the solution on the internet, but no luck.
Can you please help me?

How can I execute jar file in UNIX-like using this command line:

```
java -jar mysolution.jar < inputfile.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect and what exactly happens? `< inputfile.txt` means that your program can read the given file from the standard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `mysolution.jar` contains a main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
}
```

Anything after `mysolution.jar` in your command will be filled into the `args` String array. So if you run this:

```
java -jar mysolution.jar inputfile.txt
```

Then in your main method `args` will be an array of length 1, whose only value is the String `inputfile.txt`.

You will then have to write the code that opens that file and does something with it.

Your original approach would replace `stdin` with a file stream coming from that file. To work with the file that way you would have to use a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

[Here's another question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697922/run-java-program-by-giving-it-input-using-file-redirection) with some details on reading a file via `stdin`

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working. I'm not sure what is stdout?

Comment: `stdout` is the stream you write to for output, to get values written back out to the console. In Java we use `System.out.print` and `System.out.println` to write to it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.