# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, exception

This is my code and when I run my program with this "`java code1 3 < test.txt` "

**the test txt file contain 3 x 3 numbers grid.**

```
(47 49 14
73 4 30
2 69 71)
```

and supposed to output `191`

instead it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at code1.main(code1.java:37)
```

the purpose of this java program is to reads as a command-line argument a number n, this number is the
number of columns and rows mentioned above.
-It then reads from standard input n * n integers, each integer being between zero (0) and one
hundred (100), and then writes to standard out a single integer representing the maximum
possible profit

============

```
//args[0]=n
//args[1]=grid.txt(should be present in same directory as of your code)

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class code1{
    static int findMaxPath(int grid[][], int n) {
        int result = -1;
        // loop to find maximum if grid has n=1
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result = Math.max(result, grid[0][i]);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            result = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

                if (j > 0 && j < n - 1) // when he can come from both left-up or right-up part
                {
                    grid[i][j] += Math.max(grid[i - 1][j - 1], grid[i - 1][j + 1]);
                } else if (j > 0) // when he can come from right-up part
                {
                    grid[i][j] += grid[i - 1][j - 1];
                } else if (j < n - 1) // when he can come from left-up part
                {
                    grid[i][j] += grid[i - 1][j + 1];
                }
                result = Math.max(grid[i][j], result);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        File file = new File(args[1]);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        int grid[][] = new int[n][n];
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String arr[] = line.split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(arr[j]);
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(findMaxPath(grid, n));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is line 37? Since it's in main, either you're not giving it (enough) command line arguments; or you're not specifying `n` items in each line of input; or there are more than `n` lines of input.

Comment: Doing `< test.txt` doesn't pass it as args, but in System.in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697922/run-java-program-by-giving-it-input-using-file-redirection Just do `java code1 3 test.txt`

Comment: What should I do so when I run ` < test.txt ` will output the result I want ? @azro

Comment: It is the line after the main @AndyTurner

Comment: Do output result into a file do `java codefile > outfile.txt`, if you do `java codefile < input.txt` it sends the content of the file INTO the code to use it in the code

Comment: @azro I want to send the content of the file to be used in the code and then output 191 in the terminal. but whenever I do that I got the exception error.

Comment: Do you call your program with `java code1 3 test.txt` ? Also do `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args))` as first line in the main to be sure they are here

Comment: if I run the program with ` java codefile 3 test.txt ` it output 0 , but my homework ask to run the program using java codefile < input.txt to give the right output @azro

Comment: So use the appropriate tools https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697922/run-java-program-by-giving-it-input-using-file-redirection